# Using Ant in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ant, sublimetext

I am having trouble getting the Build command in Sublime Text 2 working with Ant. I have defined a project, and in the root of the project is a build.xml file. Then in Sublime Text 2, with the project open, I choose Tools -> Build System -> Ant. Then if I try to run Tools -> Build, I get the following output:

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
[Finished]
```

I'm sure there's something simple I'm missing. I'm on Windows XP. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Sublime Text 2 looks for the build.xml in the root of your project folder. The easiest thing might be moving your build.xml there.

Otherwise, you can change the working_dir by modifying the Ant.sublime-build (not sure where this lives in Windows, search your system for it). Alternately, you can copy the contents of that file and make a new build system (Tools -> Build System -> New Build System).

Take a look at this thread for more details: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1444&start=20

Comment: This helped me figure out the problem -- build.xml was technically in the root of my project, but I saved the sublime project file under a directory called `sublime` at the root of the project. I re-created the project without the `sublime` directory and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

User "-s" or "-find" switch. This will search for "build.xml" towards the root of the project w.r.t. current file. If you

```
{
    "cmd": ["ant", "-s"],
    "file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
    "selector": "source.java",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["ant.bat", "-s"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have occurred the same problems, but I have set up my own Ant build;
the code is

```
{
    "cmd": ["ant"],
    "file_regex": "^ *\\[javac\\] (.+):([0-9]+):() (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.java",

    "windows":
    {
        "cmd": ["ant.bat"]
    }
}
```

I've changed the `"working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}"`  to `"working_dir": "${file_path}"`.  Because, I do not like to put the very things generate by st2 in the project dir.